# Symfony2 Authentication via HTTP headers

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, curl

I have Symfony2 app running, that has login mechanism implemented.

However I need somehow to send request from other app, that checks whether requested URL exists on that system:

For example there's request http://myapp/order/1111 that I need to check whether it returns 200 OK header or 404 Not Found status;

When I send request it's unauthorized and get's redirected to login page /login which is returns 200 OK status header.

What I need is to somehow safely bypass login mechanism. Is there a way that I could add login credentials to request, or create additional login method?

## EDIT:

As suggested in comments, I tried to use curl. But I can't figure out how make it work. Here's what I'v got, but It doesn't work.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/en/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML(curl_exec($ch));

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo(curl_error($ch));
}
$csrf_token = $html->getElementById('csrf_token')->getAttribute('value');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/en/login'); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://localhost/en/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
    '_username' => 'login_username', 
    '_password' => 'login_password', 
    '_remember_me' => 'on',
    '_csrf_token' => $csrf_token
)));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo(curl_error($ch));
}

echo $result;  

curl_close($ch);
```

Any suggestions, how to work with curl on this case?

Comment: Isn't it better to get your other app authorized before checking the URL?

Comment: I agree with @smarber. By the way, if you want something simple to do  what about the request matcher explained here: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/07/symfony2-security-using-advanced-request-matchers-to-activate-firewalls/.  You can just activate the firewall only if the request doesn't have a custom header that you can simple add to your server. The drawback is the security, but it depends on tour application

Comment: I don't know how should I authorize my other app?

Comment: I meant authenticated, sorry about that. To do that and if you don't want to implement a web service you can use the classic php curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a solution to this problem if anyone else struggling with this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

//get login form
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_path); 

//parse html to get csrf_token, I added id attribute to it for easier retrieving
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML(curl_exec($ch));
$csrf_token = $html->getElementById('csrf_token')->getAttribute('value');

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}

//send post request to login_check with parameters (csrf_token included)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $check_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
    '_username' => $username, 
    '_password' => $password, 
    '_remember_me' => 'on', //if you use remember me functionality
    '_csrf_token' => $csrf_token
)));

curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}

//request login protected urls
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);

curl_exec($ch); 

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//I used this code in a function returning url and http_code for further processing
return array(
    'url' => $info['url'],
    'http_code' => $info['http_code']
);
```

I was having a problem with localization. I used to pass login_check url with locale like this http://localhost/en/login_check, by removing locate I fixed the problem: http://localhost/login_check